# .JPEG File upload shell via EXIF comments

Tags: exploit, known-vulnerabilities, file-upload

I came across [this advisory](http://www.senseofsecurity.com.au/advisories/SOS-12-009) recently and I'm a bit confused by both exploits, but specifically the file upload vulnerability. 
I don't understand how to actually exploit this condition (or even why this exists as a condition).

I tried using a shell [like this](http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/60858/aspxshell.aspx.txt.html) and inserting it into the comments section of the EXIF data, but I couldn't find any way to execute the code afterwards.

Can anyone assist? Why is it that a condition like this even exists? Is this vulnerability actually a vulnerability? Or is it just a PoC showing that you can upload things inside things (but not actually exploit them)?

Comment: I believe that this is relevant https://bechtsoudis.com/hacking/php-code-into-jpeg-metadata-from-hide-to-unhide/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What they're saying is the following:

- The upload page does not enforce file extensions, and allows you to upload an image file with an extension of `.aspx`.
- You can embed code inside a JPEG's EXIF comment tag, and it will survive the resize process (i.e. the comment tag is not stripped)
- When viewing the file, the server parses the file data as a normal ASPX page. The server outputs the binary data before the EXIF tags, sees the `<%` and then executes the code in the EXIF comment tag, stops parsing when it finds the `%>`, then outputs the remainder of the binary data.

I'm not sure whether this *actually works*, since I haven't tested it, but it sounds legit. A similar trick works with PHP, whereby any file upload system that allows you to upload an image with extension `.php` will allow you to exploit the EXIF tags by injecting `<?php /* code here */ ?>` into them.

Comment: In combination with a local file include vulnerability this would be quite powerful - ie not having to rely on poor extension filtering. I assume `include(evil_image.jpg);` would execute the embedded scripts..

Comment: @lynks If the script is dropped into the webroot,  then the attacker wouldn't need the `include()`, it can be executed directly.  +1 sounds legit.